# Edit cells dynamically in html

Tags: javascript

I want to create an function that when a button is clicked, all the data in the cells in a row will transform into input tag and when i click another button, it displays the entered data. Can someone help me with this? Is there an easier way without using jQuery?

JS:

```js
//Hash Change -------------------------
function showPage(pageId) {
 $(".page").hide();
 $(pageId).show();
}
 
location.hash = "";
location.hash = "#main";
 
$(window).on("hashchange", function(){
//console.log("Hash Changed! "+location.hash);
showPage(location.hash);
})

//Number Characters Only -------------------------
function validate(evt) {
 var theEvent = evt || window.event;
   var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
   key = String.fromCharCode( key );
   var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
   if( !regex.test(key) ) {
     theEvent.returnValue = false;
     if(theEvent.preventDefault) 
      theEvent.preventDefault();
   }
}

//Global Variables -------------------------
var positionOffered;
var date;
var name;
var cityAddress;
var cellphone1;
var emailAddress;
var dateOfBirth;
var citizenship;
var age;
var gender;

//Age function -------------------------
function submitBday() {
    var dateOfBirth = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['dateOfBirth'].value;
    var birthday = +new Date(dateOfBirth);
 age = ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}

//Main function -------------------------
function sendData() {
 
 positionOffered = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['positionOffered'].value;
 date = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['date'].value;
 name = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['name'].value;
 cityAddress = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['cityAddress'].value;
 cellphone1 = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['cellphone1'].value;
 emailAddress = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['emailAddress'].value;
 citizenship = document.getElementById('myForm').elements['citizenship'].value;
 gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
 if (gender == "male") {
  gender = "M";
 }
 else if (gender == "female") {
  gender = "F";
 }
 
 var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
 var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
 var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
 var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
 var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
    
    cell1.innerHTML = positionOffered;
    cell1.style.textAlign = "center";
    cell1.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell1.style.width = "10%";
    
    cell2.innerHTML = date;
    cell2.style.textAlign = "center";
    cell2.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell2.style.width = "10%";

 cell3.innerHTML = name;
 cell3.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell3.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell3.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell4.innerHTML = gender;
 cell4.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell4.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell4.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell5.innerHTML = age;
 cell5.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell5.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell5.style.width = "10%";

 cell6.innerHTML = cityAddress;
 cell6.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell6.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell6.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell7.innerHTML = cellphone1;
 cell7.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell7.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell7.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell8.innerHTML = emailAddress;
 cell8.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell8.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell8.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell9.innerHTML = citizenship;
 cell9.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell9.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell9.style.width = "10%";
 
 cell10.innerHTML = "<input type='button' id='edit_button' class='edit' onclick='edit_row();' value='Edit'><input type='button' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(this)' value='Delete'>";
 cell10.style.textAlign = "center";
 cell10.style.borderBottom = "thick solid black";
 cell10.style.width = "10%";
 
 reset();
 
}


//Reset -------------------------
function reset(){
 document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

//Delete Row --------------------
function delete_row(currElement) {
     var parentRowIndex = currElement.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
     document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(parentRowIndex);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  
  <head>
   <title>BIO - DATA</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylesheet.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../js/httpcode.jquery.comjquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   
   <div class="container">

    <div id="main" class="page">
     
     <center>BIO - DATA</center>
     <div class="header">PERSONAL DATA</div>
     
     <form id="myForm">
      
      <div class="main">
       
       <div class="label">
        <br>Position Desired
        <br>Name
        <br>City Address
        <br>Provincial Address
        <br>Telephone
        <br>E-mail Address
        <br>Date of Birth
        <br>Civil Status
       </div>

       <div class="input">
        <br>:<input class="short" type="text" name="positionOffered">
        <br>:<input class="short" type="text" name="name">
        <br>:<input class="long"  type="text" name="cityAddress">
        <br>:<input class="long"  type="text" name="provincialAddress">
        <br>:<input class="short" type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="15" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
        <br>:<input class="short" type="email" name="emailAddress">
        <br>:<input class="short" type="date" name="dateOfBirth" onchange="submitBday()">
        <br>:<select class="short" id="civilStatus">
          <option hidden></option>
          <option value="single">Single</option>
          <option value="married">Married</option>
          <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
          <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
          </select>
       </div>

       <div class="label">
        <br>Date
        <br>Sex
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>Cellphone
        <br>
        <br>Place of Birth
        <br>Citizenship
       </div>

       <div class="input">
        <br>:<input class="short" type="date" name="date">
        <br>:<select class="short" id="gender">
          <option hidden></option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>:<input class="short" name="cellphone1" maxlength="12" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
        <br>:<input class="short" name="cellphone2" maxlength="12" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
        <br>:<input class="short" name="placeOfBirth">
        <br>:<input class="short" name="citizenship">
       </div>


      </div>
      <input id="button" type="reset" class="button" value="Reset">
     </form>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#list"><input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendData()"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="container2">
    <div id="list" class="page">
     <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
       <td class="table">Position Desired</td>
       <td class="table">Date Filled</td>
       <td class="table">Name</td>
       <td class="table">Sex</td>
       <td class="table">Age</td>
       <td class="table">City Address</td>
       <td class="table">Cellphone </td>
       <td class="table">Email Address</td>
       <td class="table">Citizenship</td>
       <td class="table">Edit/Remove</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <a class="nav-link" href="#main"><button>Back</button></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: why don't you want to use jQuery?

Comment: If you want our help with your problem (which, from your description of the problem, shouldn't be all that hard) you *really* need to reduce that wall of code to the "*[mcve]*" code necessary to reproduce your problem. I don't believe we need all the HTML content, nor all the JavaScript functions, you've posted. We definitely don't need the various scripts, or stylesheets, that use a relative address (since no file exists at that relative address here on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you were looking for:

Pressing the Edit Button will turn all the 's into  tags while persisting the data in each tag.

```js
var row = document.querySelector('.row');
var cells = $(row).children('.cell');

var turnInputButton = document.querySelector("button#turnInput");
var saveButton = document.querySelector("#save");

var inputs;

$(turnInputButton).on('click', function() {
  $.each(cells, function(i) {
    if (cells[i].tagName === 'TD') {
      var temp = cells[i].textContent;
      var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.value = temp;
      $(cells[i]).replaceWith(input);

      inputs = $(row).children('input');
    }
  });
});

$(saveButton).on('click', function() {
  $.each(inputs, function(i) {
    if (inputs[i].tagName === 'INPUT') {
      var temp = inputs[i].value;
      var td = document.createElement("TD");
      td.setAttribute("class", "cell");
      td.textContent = temp;
      $(inputs[i]).replaceWith(td);

      cells = $(row).children('.cell');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container2">
    <div id="list" class="page">
      <button id="turnInput">Edit</button>
      <button id="save">Save</button>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="row">
          <td class="cell">Position Desired</td>
          <td class="cell">Date Filled</td>
          <td class="cell">Name</td>
          <td class="cell">Sex</td>
          <td class="cell">Age</td>
          <td class="cell">City Address</td>
          <td class="cell">Cellphone </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/waldalvajr/7wahro8n/